# Can I parse XML data to google map for the location?

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

Can I parse XML data to google map for the location?
is there any tutorial , etc that I can follow through?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get it. can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: What I mean was
retrieve the location for each event(XML DATA) from a URL and it will display the location for the event on the google map.

Comment: You can parse your XML and then get the relevant latitude and longitude values from it. Then once you have them, you can show it on map.

Comment: how do you do it?
I've post sort of similar question here, 
so take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823436/how-do-i-can-i-retrieve-location-data-and-display-it-on-google-map